# Ngsrc not showing image at all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image

I am having problem with ngsrc because I cant found out why my image is not showing when calling from controller... My code looks like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="createProfileCtrl">
    <div><img class="img-circle" ng-src="{{profilePicture}}" alt="placeholder"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my javascript code looks like this:

```
var chApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('createProfileCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.profilePicture = '/images/background.jpg'

}]);
```

I have image added in images folder and I still dont get result in a view(html)

Comment: What is response for `/images/background.jpg`?

Comment: There is no response. I am using express node.js app framework for my project and thats how I call my image inside an html. When I put this code in my view :
     <img ng-src="/images/background.jpg" alt=""/> 

Image is showing, but when I call it from controller, It doesnt :{ @Andrey

Comment: Shouldn't your tag be self closing btw? In code from post there is `<img ... >`, not `<img ... />`

Comment: Nahh.. That's not to problem and I just checked it out :( Even when I set  $scope.profilePic = 'http://fakeimg.pl/150x150/222/FFF/?text=150x150'; It doesnt work.. @Andrey

Comment: To make fakeimg picture show - you should add `//` before url to make it absolute. See [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kofamasafi/1/edit?html,js,output) - your code workning fine

Comment: @Andrey I added but when I paste it here it gets removed.. I am new on this stackoverflow site but however, It seems that there is a problem with my app structure. When I create a new HTML5 boilerplate its working just fine, but not here with Node.js Express framework..

Comment: So i think you should add some server code, console ouput of server and browser, because now it's difficult to understand what is wrong